# View with multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I have two tables in my database that have similar data but not same.

I'd like to show these tables in the same view. Looking in internet the most suggested practice is to use a ViewModel class.

So... These are my class tables:

iCareIndoorAlert.cs

```
[Table("iCareIndoorAlerts")]
public class iCareIndoorAlert
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("ID Allarme iCare indoor")]
    public long AlertID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("ID Messaggio")]
    public long MessageID { get; set; }

    public string UUID { get; set; }

    public int MAG { get; set; }

    public int MIN { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Distanza")]
    public float Dist { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data ora")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual HttpPop3 HttpPop3 { get; set; }
}
```

iCareOutdoorAlert.cs

```
[Table("iCareOutdoorAlerts")]
public class iCareOutdoorAlert
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("ID Allarme iCare outdoor")]
    public long AlertID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("ID Messaggio")]
    public long MessageID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Latitudine")]
    public float Lat { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Longitudine")]
    public float Lon { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Accuracy")]
    public float Acc { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data ora")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

After I created a ViewModel folder with a iCareAlertViewModel.cs class:

```
    public List<iCareIndoorAlert> iCareIndoorAlert { get; set; }
    public List<iCareOutdoorAlert> iCareOutdoorAlert { get; set; }
```

And added there rows in the iCareEntities.cs:

```
    public DbSet<iCareIndoorAlert> iCareIndoorAlerts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<iCareOutdoorAlert> iCareOutdoorAlerts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<iCareAlertViewModel> iCareAlertsViewModels { get; set; }
```

After I generated the iCareAlertController.cs and run the view Index.cshtml but I get the error "Key not found". So in the ViewModel I added a dummy variable with [Key] attribute and now a get an error that says that can't find the iCareAlertViewModel table...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you start class name from lowercase letter and why this is letter is "i"?

Comment: Becouse the project which I'm working on is called, at the moment, "iCare" and the Android application the send me the alerts via SMS has the same name. I called my Visual Studio project iCare too.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't create a DbSet for your view model, that's not necessary. A view model is a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) that sits between your data models (i.e. your entities) and your user interface.

What you probably need to do is define an interface that has the properties that are common to your two entities, so something like this:

```
public interface IAlert
{
    long AlertID { get; set; }
    long MessageID { get; set; }
    //etc...
}
```

Now each entity can implement that interface:

```
public class iCareIndoorAlert : IAlert
{
    //snip
}
```

Now your viewmodel:

```
public class AlertViewModel : IAlert
{
    public long AlertID { get; set; }
    public long MessageID { get; set; }
    //snip        
}
```

So your view will now be something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<My.Assembly.AlertViewModel>

@foreach(var alert in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AlertID)
    //etc
}
```

Finally you need something to map your entities to your view model, you can use a library like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) but manually, it's something like this (including the action method and return):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<IAlert> alerts = GetOutdoorAlerts(); //for example

    List<AlertViewModel> alertViewModels = alert
        .Select(a => new AlertViewModel
        {
             AlertID = a.AlertID,
             MessageID = a.MessageID,
             //etc...
        });

    return View(alertViewModels);
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the code, really... Tell me if it's right: the IAlert class has all the properties that are the same between the two tables. In my case AlertID, MessageID, UUID and DateTime. Then I have to create two extension of that class. iCareIndoorAlert.cs with the properties MAG, MIN and Dist and iCareOutdoorAlert.cs with the properties Lat, Lon, Acc. If since now it's right I'm missing something on the ViewModel creation. Why again AlertID and MessageID?